# how many visitor open this post?

Tags: posts, homepage

i want to create, how many visitor open this post it display in homepage below of summary [like this](http://www.desyfun.tk/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/2012-10-23_161718.jpg) .how i can do it? [my site](http://www.dewdropzone.com).my css code

```
/***** Structure and Layout *****/
body { font: 62.5% Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666; }
#angles { position: relative; width: 100%; }
.inner-wrapper { position: relative; width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; }
#column-container { position: relative; width: 960px; background: #fff url(images/backgrounds/bg-sidebar.gif) repeat-y top right; padding: 20px 0 0; }
#column-container-left { position: relative; width: 960px; background: #fff url(images/backgrounds/bg-sidebar.gif) repeat-y top left; padding: 20px 0; }
#column-container-wide { position: relative; width: 960px; background: #fff; padding: 20px 0; }
#left-column, #right-column { position: relative; width: 640px; }
#right-sidebar, #left-sidebar { position: relative; width: 320px; }
#right-sidebar, #right-column { float: right; }
#left-column, #left-sidebar { float: left; }
.video-sidebar { position: relative; width: 300px; margin: 0 10px 20px; padding: 0 0 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9; }

/***** Float Classes and Clear Float Fix *****/
.clear { display: inline-block; }
.clear:after { display: block; visibility: hidden; clear: both; height: 0; content: "."; }
/* Hide from IE Mac \*/ .clear { display: block; } /* End hide from IE Mac */
.alignleft { float: left; }
.alignright { float: right; }

/***** Main Nav Bar *****/
#mainnav-bar { position: relative; width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; background: #fcfcfc url(images/backgrounds/bg-main-nav.jpg) repeat-x bottom left; border: 1px solid #d9d9d9; z-index: 98; }

/***** Main Navigation *****/
#mainnav-bar ul { position: relative; float: left }
#mainnav-bar li { float: left; background: url(images/backgrounds/pipe-mainnav.gif) repeat-y top right; line-height: 40px; position: relative; }
#mainnav-bar li:hover { visibility: inherit; }
#mainnav-bar li a, #mainnav-bar li a:visited { display: block; color: #464646; font-size: 1.3em; font-weight: bold; padding: 0 15px; text-decoration: none; position: relative; }
#mainnav-bar li a:hover, #mainnav-bar li a:active { color: #fff; background: #464646 url(images/backgrounds/bg-main-nav-hover.png) repeat-x top left; }

/***** Main Navigation Dropdown Menu *****/
#mainnav-bar ul ul { position: absolute; top: -999em; width: 20em; background: #e6e6e6; border-left: 1px solid #d9d9d9; border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9; border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9; background-image: none; margin: 0; }
#mainnav-bar ul ul li { clear: left; width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9; padding: 0; background-image: none !important; line-height: 3em; }
#mainnav-bar ul ul li:first-child { border: none; }
#mainnav-bar ul ul li a, #mainnav-bar ul ul li a:visited { font-size: 1.1em !important; color: #323232; background-image: none !important; }
#mainnav-bar ul ul li a:hover, #mainnav-bar ul ul li a:active { background: #1b1b1b; color: #fff !important; }

/***** Show Main Navigation Dropdown Menu *****/
#mainnav-bar ul li:hover ul, #mainnav-bar ul li.sfHover ul { top: 4.1em; left: 0; z-index: 99; }

/***** Hide Main Navigation Flyout Navigation Level 1 - 3 *****/
#mainnav-bar ul ul li:hover ul, #mainnav-bar ul ul li.sfHover ul,
#mainnav-bar ul ul ul li:hover ul, #mainnav-bar ul ul ul li.sfHover ul,
#mainnav-bar ul ul ul ul li:hover ul, #mainnav-bar ul ul ul ul li.sfHover ul { top: -999em; }

/***** Show Main Navigation Flyout Navigation Level 1 - 3 *****/
#mainnav-bar ul ul li:hover ul, #mainnav-bar ul ul li.sfHover ul,
#mainnav-bar ul ul ul li:hover ul, #mainnav-bar ul ul ul li.sfHover ul,
#mainnav-bar ul ul ul ul li:hover ul, #mainnav-bar ul ul ul ul li.sfHover ul { top: 0; left: 20em; }

/***** Main Navigation Current Menu Item Highlighting *****/
#mainnav-bar ul li:hover, #mainnav-bar ul li.sfHover:hover { background: url(images/backgrounds/pipe-mainnav.gif) repeat-y top right; }
#mainnav-bar ul ul li:hover, #mainnav-bar ul ul li.sfHover:hover { background: #d5d5d5; background-image: none; }

/***** Home Page Magazine Content *****/
.headlines { position: relative; width: 640px; background: url(images/backgrounds/bg-home-columns.gif) no-repeat center top; padding: 15px 0 0; margin: 0 0 20px; }
.home-column { position: relative; width: 300px; float: left; padding: 0 10px; }
.home-column h2 a, .home-column h2 a:visited { font-size: 1.1em; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none; padding: 0 8px 0 0; }
.home-column ul { margin: 10px 0 0; }
.home-column li { padding: 10px 0; border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7; width: 300px; overflow: hidden; }
.home-column .home-thumb li { overflow: hidden; width: 300px; }
.thumb-text { position: relative; width: 220px; float: right; }
.home-column h3 a, .home-column h3 a:visited { font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: normal; color: #464646; text-decoration: none; line-height: 1.5; }
.home-column p { color: #a5a5a5; font: 1.2em/1.5 'VollkornItalic', serif; margin: 1px 0 0; }
.home-column .sidebar-archive-thumb p, .home-column .lead-thumb p { margin: 0; }
.home-column p a, .home-column p a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
.home-column p a:hover, .home-column p a:active { text-decoration: underline; }
.home-headlines h3 a, .home-headlines h3 a:visited { background: url(images/backgrounds/list-arrow.png) no-repeat 0 0.3em; display: block; padding: 0 0 0 15px; }
.home-headlines p { margin: 1px 0 0 15px; }
.lead-thumb { position: relative; }
.lead-thumb a, .lead-thumb a:visited { display: block; width: 290px; height: 125px; border: 5px solid #f1f1f1; margin: 0 0 10px; -webkit-transition: border .2s linear; transition: border .2s linear; }
.lead-thumb a:hover, .lead-thumb a:active { -webkit-transition: border .2s linear; transition: border .2s linear; }

/***** Home Page Blog Content *****/
.home-blog { position: relative; width: 600px; margin: 0 10px; border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9; border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9; border-left: 1px solid #d9d9d9; padding: 10px 9px;  }
.home-blog-thumb { position: relative; width: 130px; height: 130px; float: left; background: #f1f1f1; border: 1px solid #d9d9d9; padding: 4px; }
.home-blog-thumb:hover { border-color: #bbb; }
.home-blog-thumb .play-button { position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 30px; }
.home-blog-text { position: relative; width: 440px; float: right; }
.home-blog-text h3 a, .home-blog-text h3 a:visited { color: #464646; font-size: 1.8em; line-height: 1.2em; text-decoration: none; letter-spacing: -.02em; }
.home-blog-text p { font-size: 1.2em; line-height: 1.6em; margin: 10px 0 0; }
.home-blog-text p a, .home-blog-text p a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
.home-blog-text p a:hover, .home-blog-text p a:active { text-decoration: underline; }
.home-blog-cat { position: relative; width: 620px; height: 35px; margin: 0 10px 20px; background: url(images/backgrounds/bg-home-cat.jpg) no-repeat 0 0; }
.home-blog-cat p { line-height: 35px; font-size: 1.1em; background: url(images/backgrounds/bg-cat-links.jpg) no-repeat top right; padding: 0 15px 0 10px; color: #fff; display: inline-block; }
.home-blog-cat p a, .home-blog-cat p a:visited { color: #fff; text-decoration: none; }
.home-blog-cat p a:hover, .home-blog-cat p a:active { text-decoration: underline; }

/***** Breadcrumbs *****/
#breadcrumbs { position: relative; width: 620px; margin: 0 10px 20px; }
#breadcrumbs p { font-size: 1.1em; line-height: 1.4em; }
#breadcrumbs p a, #breadcrumbs p a:visited { font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; }
#breadcrumbs p a:hover, #breadcrumbs p a:active { text-decoration: underline; }
#breadcrumbs p span.current-crumb { font-weight: bold; }

/***** Page Titles *****/
#page-title, #page-title-wide { position: relative; margin: 0 10px 20px; background: url(images/backgrounds/divider.png) no-repeat bottom center; padding: 0 0 20px; }
#page-title { width: 620px; }
#page-title-wide { width: 940px; }
#page-title h1, #page-title-wide h1 { color: #222; font: 3em/1.2 'VollkornRegular', serif; letter-spacing: -.03em; }

/***** Post Header *****/
#post-header { position: relative; width: 618px; margin: 0 10px 20px; background: #f1f1f1; border: 1px solid #d9d9d9; padding: 10px 0 0; overflow: hidden; }
#post-header-wide { position: relative; width: 618px; margin: 0 10px 20px; background: #f1f1f1; border: 1px solid #d9d9d9; padding: 10px 0 0; }
.post-title { position: relative; width: 618px; }
.header-gravatar { position: relative; width: 80px; height: 60px; float: left; background: url(images/backgrounds/bg-header-avatar.gif) no-repeat right 10px; margin: 0 0 0 9px; z-index: 2; }
.header-gravatar img { display: block; border: 5px solid #fff; }
.header-title { position: relative; background: #fff; border: 1px solid #d9d9d9; padding: 10px; }
#post-header .header-title { width: 498px; float: left; margin: 0 0 0 -1px; }
#post-header-wide .header-title { width: 576px; margin: 0 0 0 9px; }
.header-title h1 { color: #222; font: 2.5em/1.2 'VollkornRegular', serif; letter-spacing: -.03em; }
#post-data { position: relative; width: 618px; margin: 10px 0 0; }
#post-data-wide { position: relative; width: 525; margin: 0 10px 0 0; float: left; }
#post-comments { position: relative; width: 75px; margin: 0 0 0 10px; float: right; }

/***** Post Data *****/
#post-data p { font-size: 1.1em; line-height: 1.4em; color: #222; background: url(images/backgrounds/bg-post-header.gif) repeat-x left top; padding: 10px; }
#post-data p a, #post-data p a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
#post-data p a:hover, #post-data p a:active { text-decoration: underline; }

/***** Share Post Actions *****/
.share-actions { position: relative; width: 140px; margin: 0 0 0 10px; }
.share-actions li { border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9; border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9; border-left: 1px solid #d9d9d9; padding: 15px 20px; text-align: center; }
.share-button, .share-button:visited { display: inline-block; line-height: 2em; text-align: center; background: #e5e5e5 url(images/backgrounds/bg-button.png) repeat-x 0 0; padding: 0 10px; border: 1px solid #d9d9d9; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color: #464646; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.1em; text-decoration: none; }
.share-button:hover, .share-button:active { border-color: #b9b9b9; }
.post-left-column .widget-head { margin: 0 10px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center; }
.post-left-column p { margin: 0 10px 20px; text-align: center; }

/***** Post Lead Image *****/
#lead-image { position: relative; width: 610px; height: 320px; margin: 0 10px 20px; padding: 5px; background: url(images/backgrounds/bg-postthumb.gif); }
#lead-image img { display: block; }



/***** Post Meta *****/
.published { position: relative; width: 620px; margin: 0 10px 20px; background: url(images/backgrounds/bg-published.gif) repeat-x 0 0; text-align: center; }
.published p { background: #fff url(images/backgrounds/bg-published-decoration.gif) no-repeat center bottom; display: inline-block; color: #222; font: 1.2em 'VollkornItalic', serif; padding: 0 10px 20px; }
.published p a, .published p a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
.published p a:hover, .published p a:active { text-decoration: underline; }

/***** Post YouTube Video Player *****/
#video-player { position: relative; width: 620px; margin: 0 10px 20px; }
.yt-player { width: 615px; height: 370px; }

/***** Post Entry *****/
.post-columns { position: relative; width: 640px; }
.post-460 { position: relative; width: 460px; margin: 0 10px; float: right; }
.post-620, .periodic-password-post { position: relative; width: 620px; margin: 0 10px; }
.post-940 { width: 940px; margin: 0 10px; }
.post-left-column { position: relative; width: 160px; float: left; margin: 0 0 20px; }
.post-entry { position: relative; }
.post-entry h1, .post-entry h2, .post-entry h3, .post-entry h4, .post-entry h5, .post-entry h6 { margin: 0 0 10px; color: #222; line-height: 1.7; }
.post-entry h1 { font-size: 2.1em; }
.post-entry h2 { font-size: 1.9em; }
.post-entry h3 { font-size: 1.7em; }
.post-entry h4 { font-size: 1.5em; }
.post-entry h5 { font-size: 1.3em; }
.post-entry h6 { font-size: 1.2em; }
.post-entry p { font-size: 1.3em; line-height: 1.7em; margin: 0 0 30px; }
.post-entry blockquote { margin: 0 40px; border-left: 3px solid #464646; padding: 0 0 0 20px; font: 120% 'VollkornItalic', serif; color: #222; }
.post-entry blockquote p { line-height: 1.5em; }
.post-entry ul, .post-entry ol { margin: 0 40px 30px; font-size: 1.3em; line-height: 1.7em; }
.post-entry ul { list-style: disc; }
.post-entry ul ul { margin: 0 0 0 30px; font-size: inherit; list-style: circle; }
.post-entry ul ol { margin: 0 0 0 30px; font-size: inherit; }
.post-entry ul ul li { background: none; padding: 0; }
.post-entry ol { list-style: decimal; }
.post-entry dl { font-size: 1.3em; line-height: 1.7em; }
.post-entry dt { color: #222; font-weight: bold; }
.post-entry dd { margin: 0 0 30px; }
.post-entry code { font: 90% Monaco, Courier, monospace; background: #f1f1f1; padding: 2px; border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9; border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9; }
.post-entry p a, .post-entry li a,
.post-entry p a:visited, .post-entry li a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
.post-entry p a:hover, .post-entry li a:hover,
.post-entry p a:active, .post-entry li a:active { text-decoration: underline; }
.post-entry table { width: 90%; border-left: 1px solid #d9d9d9; margin: 0 auto 20px; }
.post-entry table caption { line-height: 3em; font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: bold; color: #464646; }
.post-entry table thead, .post-entry table tfoot { background: #f1f1f1; }
.post-entry table th, .post-entry table td { padding: 10px 15px; text-align: left; border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9; border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9; font-size: 1.2em; color: #464646; }
.post-entry tfoot td { text-align: center; }
.post-entry table th { border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9; font-weight: bold; }
.post-entry table td a, .post-entry table td a:visited { font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; }
.post-entry table td a:hover, .post-entry table td a:active { text-decoration: underline; }
.post-entry pre { font-size: 1.4em; background: url(images/backgrounds/bg-pre.gif) top left; line-height: 2.3em; width: 600px; overflow: auto; overflow-y: hidden; border: 1px solid #d9d9d9; margin: 0 0 20px; }
.post-entry pre code { background: none; border: none; font-size: inherit; margin: 0 20px; padding: 18px 0; }
.post-entry address { font-style: normal; font-size: 1.3em; line-height: 1.5em; margin: 0 0 20px; }
.post-entry strong { color: #464646; }

/***** Post Entry Password Form ****/
.post-entry form label { font-weight: bold; }
.post-entry form input[type='password'] { width: 280px; padding: 7px 10px; border: 5px solid #f1f1f1; color: #d9d9d9; margin: 5px 0 0; }
.post-entry form input[type='password']:focus { color: #797979; }
.post-entry form input[type='submit'] { width: 140px; height: 40px; margin: 0 0 20px; background: url(images/backgrounds/periodic-sprite-03.png) no-repeat 0 -340px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial, "Helvetia Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase; color: #797979; margin: 10px 0 0; }
.post-entry form input[type='submit']:hover { background-position: 0 -430px; cursor: pointer; }

/***** Shortcodes *****/
.post-entry blockquote.pullquote { margin: 0 20px; padding: 0; width: 35%; border: none; color: #464646; }
.post-entry blockquote.pullquote p { margin: 0; }
.post-entry blockquote.pullright { padding: 5px 0 5px 20px; border-left: 3px solid #464646; }
.post-entry blockquote.pullleft { padding: 5px 20px 5px 0; border-right: 3px solid #464646; text-align: right; }
.checklist { position: relative; }
.checklist ul { list-style: none; }
.checklist li { background: url(images/backgrounds/check.png) no-repeat left .4em; padding: 0 0 0 20px; }
.arrowlist { position: relative; }
.arrowlist ul { list-style: none; }
.arrowlist li { background: url(images/backgrounds/list-arrow.png) no-repeat 0 .4em; padding: 0 0 0 15px; }
.arrowlist li li { background: none; padding: 0; }
.note { position: relative; width: 75%; margin: 0 auto 30px; background: #f1f1f1; border: 1px solid #d9d9d9; padding: 10px 20px 14px; }
.note p { margin: 0; font: 1.4em/1.6em 'VollkornItalic', serif; }
.two_column { position: relative; width: 47%; margin: 0 20px 0 0; float: left; }
.two_column_last { position: relative; width: 47%; margin: 0; float: left; }
.three_column { position: relative; width: 31%; margin: 0 20px 0 0; float: left; }
.three_column_last { position: relative; width: 31%; margin: 0; float: left; }
.four_column { position: relative; width: 23%; margin: 0 20px 0 0; float: left; }
.four_column_last { position: relative; width: 23%; margin: 0; float: left; }
.button, .button:visited { display: inline-block; line-height: 2.5em; text-align: center; background: #e5e5e5 url(images/backgrounds/bg-button.png) repeat-x 0 0; padding: 0 25px; border: 5px solid #d9d9d9; -moz-border-radius: 20px; -webkit-border-radius: 20px; border-radius: 20px; margin: 0 0 20px; color: #464646; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em; text-decoration: none; }
.button:hover, .button:active { background-color: #fcfcfc; background-position: 0 -40px; border-color: #b9b9b9; }

/***** Post Images *****/
img.alignleft { margin: 0 20px 10px 0; }
img.alignright { margin: 0 0 10px 20px; }
img.aligncenter { margin: 0 auto; }

/***** Post Images with Captions *****/
.wp-caption { background: #f3f3f3; border: 1px solid #d9d9d9; padding: 4px 0; }
.wp-caption img { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
.wp-caption .wp-caption-text { text-align: center; margin: 5px 0 3px; line-height: 1; font: 1.2em/1.3 'VollkornItalic', serif; color: #464646; }
div.alignleft { margin: 0 20px 10px 0; }
div.alignright { margin: 0 0 10px 20px; }
div.aligncenter { margin: 0 auto 20px; }

/***** Post Image Galleries *****/
.gallery { margin: 0 0 20px !important; }
.gallery-item img { border: 1px solid #d9d9d9 !important; background: #f1f1f1; padding: 4px; }
.post-entry dd.gallery-caption { margin: 0 0 15px; padding: 0 20px; }
.post-entry dd.wp-caption-text { font-family: 'VollkornItalic', serif; color: #464646; line-height: 1.2em; }

/***** Post Share *****/
#post-share { position: relative; width: 620px; margin: 0 10px 20px; }
#post-share li { line-height: 0; float: left; margin: 0 30px 0 0; }

/***** Author Box *****/
.post-gravatar { position: relative; width: 60px; height: 60px; margin: 0 10px 0 0; float: left; }
.post-gravatar img { display: block; width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid #d9d9d9; background: #fcfcfc; padding: 4px; }
#author-box, #archived-author-box { position: relative; width: 598px; margin: 0 10px 20px; background: #f1f1f1; border: 1px solid #d9d9d9; padding: 10px; }
#author-box h3 { color: #222; font-size: 1.1em; margin: 0 0 10px; text-transform: uppercase; }
#author-text, #archived-author-text { position: relative; width: 528px; float: right; }
#author-text p { font-size: 1.2em; line-height: 1.6em; margin: 0 0 10px; }
#archived-author-text p { font-size: 1.2em; line-height: 1.6em; }
#author-text p a, #author-text p a:visited,
#archived-author-text p a, #archived-author-text p a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
#author-text p a:hover, #author-text p a:active,
#archived-author-text p a:hover, #archived-author-text p a:active { text-decoration: underline; }

/***** Post Archives *****/
#archived-posts { position: relative; width: 640px; }
#archived-posts .widget-head { margin: 0 11px 0 10px; border-bottom: none; }
#archived-posts ul { width: 618px; border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9; border-left: 1px solid #d9d9d9; margin: 0 10px; }
#archived-posts li { line-height: 0; width: 308px; border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9; border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9; padding: 20px 0; float: left; }
#archived-posts li.no-articles { border: none; font: 1.4em/1.6em 'VollkornItalic', serif; background: #fff; width: 100%; margin: 0 0 0 -1px; }
.post-archive { position: relative; width: 300px; margin: 0 10px; padding: 20px 0; }
#archived-posts .post-archive { padding: 0; width: 280px; margin: 0 auto; }
#archived-posts .archive-thumb { width: 280px; }
#archived-posts .archive-thumb .hot-topic { left: 5px; bottom: 5px; }
.archive-thumb { position: relative; width: 300px; }
.archive-thumb a, .archive-thumb a:visited { display: block; width: 270px; height: 120px; border: 5px solid #f1f1f1; margin: 0 0 10px; -webkit-transition: border .2s linear; transition: border .2s linear; }
.archive-thumb a:hover, .archive-thumb a:active { -webkit-transition: border .2s linear; transition: border .2s linear; }
.video-archive-thumb .yt-thumb, .video-archive-thumb .attachment-thumbnail-archive { display: block; border: 5px solid #f1f1f1; margin: 0 0 10px; }
.archive-text, .callout-archive-text { position: relative; padding: 0 5px; }
#recent-articles .archive-text { width: 195px; margin: 0 5px 0 0; float: right; padding: 0; }
.archive-text h3 a, .archive-text h3 a:visited,
.archive-text h4 a, .archive-text h4 a:visited { color: #464646; text-decoration: none; font-size: 1.2em; line-height: 1.6em; -webkit-transition: color .2s linear; transition: color .2s linear; }
.archive-text h3 a:hover, .archive-text h3 a:active,
.archive-text h4 a:hover, .archive-text h4 a:active { -webkit-transition: color .2s linear; transition: color .2s linear; }
.archive-text p { margin: 10px 0 0; font-size: 1.2em; line-height: 1.6em; }
.archive-text .meta-data { font-size: 1.1em; line-height: 1.6em; }
.archive-text p a, .archive-text p a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
.archive-text p a:hover, .archive-text p a:active { text-decoration: underline; }
.play-archive { position: absolute; top: -110px; left: 110px; border: none !important; }
#archive-error { position: relative; width: 620px; margin: 0 10px 20px; border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9; padding: 20px 0 0; }
#category-description { position: relative; width: 620px; margin: 0 10px 20px; }
#category-description p { font: 1.4em/1.6em 'VollkornItalic', serif; }

/***** Related Posts *****/
.rel-post { position: relative; width: 280px; margin: 0 auto; }
.rel-post-text { position: relative; width: 200px; float: right; }
.rel-post-text h4 a, .rel-post-text h4 a:visited { color: #464646; text-decoration: none; font-size: 1.1em; line-height: 1.3em; -webkit-transition: color .2s linear; transition: color .2s linear; font-weight: normal;  }
.rel-post-text h4 a:hover, .rel-post-text h4 a:active { -webkit-transition: color .2s linear; transition: color .2s linear; }
.rel-post-text p { margin: 5px 0 0; font-size: 1.1em; line-height: 1.3em; }
.rel-post-text p a, .rel-post-text p a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
.rel-post-text p a:hover, .rel-post-text p a:active { text-decoration: underline; }
.related { margin: 0 0 20px; }


/***** Contributors Page *****/
.contributors-list { position: relative; width: 620px; margin: 0 10px; }
.contributors-list li { overflow: hidden; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #d9d9d9; margin: 0 0 20px; }
.contribute-avatar { position: relative; width: 85px; height: 85px; float: left; }
.contribute-text { position: relative; width: 493px; float: right; }
.contribute-avatar a, .contribute-avatar a:visited { display: block; width: 75px; height: 75px; border: 5px solid #f1f1f1; -webkit-transition: border .2s linear; transition: border .2s linear; }
.contribute-avatar a:hover, .contribute-avatar a:active { -webkit-transition: border .2s linear; transition: border .2s linear; }
.contribute-text h3 a, .contribute-text h3 a:visited { font-size: 1.4em; line-height: 1.5em; color: #464646; text-decoration: none; -webkit-transition: color .2s linear; transition: color .2s linear; }
.contribute-text h3 a:hover, .contribute-text h3 a:active { -webkit-transition: color .2s linear; transition: color .2s linear; }
.contribute-text p { font-size: 1.2em; line-height: 1.5em; margin: 10px 0 0; }
.contribute-text p a, .contribute-text p a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
.contribute-text p a:hover, .contribute-text p a:active { text-decoration: underline; }

/***** Form Elements *****/
.form-wrapper { position: relative; width: 620px; margin: 0 0 20px; }
.form-wrapper p { font-size: 1.2em; line-height: 1.5em; margin: 0 0 20px; }
.form-wrapper p a, .form-wrapper p a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
.form-wrapper p a:hover, .form-wrapper p a:active { text-decoration: underline; }
.form-wrapper p code { font: 90% Monaco, Courier, monospace; }
.form-field-wrapper { position: relative; display: block; margin: 0 0 20px; }
.form-wrapper label, .wpcf7 label { display: block; font-size: 1.1em; line-height: 1; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0 0 5px; }
.form-wrapper label em, .wpcf7 label em { font-style: normal; }
.text-input { width: 280px; padding: 7px 10px; border: 5px solid #f1f1f1; font: 1.35em/1 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #d9d9d9; }
.text-input:focus { color: #797979; }
.textarea-input { width: 520px; height: 250px; border: 5px solid #f1f1f1; font: 1.35em/1.5em "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #d9d9d9; padding: 7px 10px; overflow: auto; }
.textarea-input:focus { color: #797979; }
.form-submit { width: 140px; height: 40px; margin: 0 0 20px; background: url(images/backgrounds/periodic-sprite-03.png) no-repeat 0 -340px; font: bold 1.1em/1 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase; color: #797979; margin: 0 0 0 410px; }
.wpcf7 .form-submit { font-size: inherit; }
.form-submit:hover { background-position: 0 -430px; cursor: pointer; }

/***** Misc *****/
.right-arrow { padding: 0 9px 0 0; }
.scroll-top { display: block; width: 40px; height: 40px; text-indent: -9999px; background: url(images/backgrounds/periodic-sprite-03.png) no-repeat 0 -520px; }
.scroll-top:hover { background-position: 0 -610px; }
.rss { background: url(images/backgrounds/periodic-sprite.png) no-repeat 0 -658px; padding: 1px 0 2px 21px; }
.last { margin: 0 !important; }
.play-button { display: block; width: 70px; height: 70px; text-indent: -9999px; background: url(images/backgrounds/periodic-sprite-03.png) no-repeat 0 0; }
.play-button:hover { background-position: 0 -120px; }
.error-message { font-size: 1.2em; }
.divider { border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9; }
.meta-info { font: 1.1em/1 'VollkornItalic', serif; display: block; color: #a5a5a5; margin: 5px 0 0 15px; }

/***** Post & Page Pagination *****/
.post-pager { border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9; font-family: 'VollkornItalic', serif; color: #222; padding: 10px 0 0; font-size: 1.4em !important; }
.post-pager span { margin: 0 5px 0 0; }
.post-pager a { margin: 0 5px; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  simplest solution would be by using a plugin. For instance: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/baw-post-views-count/. Your CSS has nothing to do with it